# cloud adoption vs cloud migration

Tags: migration, cloud

what is the difference between cloud adoption and cloud migration?

As far as I'm concerned cloud adoption is utilizing different services from csp where as cloud migration is migrating from on-premise to cloud. But some scholars consider it as a the same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Adoption is delegating some process or intangibles to the cloud, like using a cloud repo, cloud based service instances etc.

Cloud Migration on the other-hand is moving the entire setup from physical bare metal to hosted system on the internet ( which is called as cloud).